# Node-RED Stability

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I've recently had to jump back into development using MEAN on the server-side. Having been thrown in at the deep end with node.js, I wanted to apply my new found understanding to the Node-RED environment. My previous attempts to get my BBB and Raspberries working with a stable version of Node-RED always proved fruitless.

Is there any reason why particular configurations of Node-RED aren't locked down like notable version changes in mongodb for example? My question is prompted by my previous frustration and today's bug I replicated on a Bitnami MEAN stack on Windows.

https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/565

I can try and roll-back to the suggested versions of modules in the package.json but that seems extreme. Any clarification would be appreciated.

**My dead-in-the-water editor error today:**

```
C:\Bitnami\meanstack-3.0.2-0\projects\node-red>node-red


Welcome to Node-RED
===================

19 Jun 18:36:16 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.10.10
19 Jun 18:36:16 - [info] Node.js  version: v0.12.2
19 Jun 18:36:16 - [info] Loading palette nodes
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [warn] Failed to register 5 node types
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [warn] Run with -v for details
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [info] Settings file  : ./settings
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [info] User Directory : \Users\xxx\.node-red
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [info] Flows file     : \Users\xxx\.node-red\flows_Opti
plex790.json
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [info] Creating new flows file
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [info] Starting flows
19 Jun 18:36:17 - [info] Started flows
19 Jun 18:37:50 - [red] Uncaught Exception:
19 Jun 18:37:50 - TypeError: argument entity must be string, Buffer, or fs.Stats

    at etag (C:\Bitnami\meanstack-3.0.2-0\nodejs\node_modules\node-red\node_modu
les\express\node_modules\send\node_modules\etag\index.js:55:11)
    at SendStream.setHeader (C:\Bitnami\meanstack-3.0.2-0\nodejs\node_modules\no
de-red\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:724:15)
    at SendStream.send (C:\Bitnami\meanstack-3.0.2-0\nodejs\node_modules\node-re
d\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:500:8)
    at onstat (C:\Bitnami\meanstack-3.0.2-0\nodejs\node_modules\node-red\node_mo
dules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:585:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)

C:\Bitnami\meanstack-3.0.2-0\projects\node-red>
```

Comment: Well this is a question for the project owner(s), not SO.

Answer (score 4):

The project's `package.json` **does** specify [specific versions](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/package.json#L27) of all main dependencies.

The problem here is that you are running on Node 0.12.

As per the [installation instructions](http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/installation.html), the [release notes](http://blog.nodered.org/2015/06/16/version-0-10-8-released/) and the [open issue you link to](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/565), Node-RED does not support Node 0.12 yet.

If you are looking for specific help, I suggest you use the project's [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and my apologies. I should have taken the time to digest the project updates having been involved in other projects. Some sleep on my part would also help! Thanks again.